# How do I create a Singleton in Android that needs a Context?

Tags: java, android, enums, singleton

I recently learned about using enums in Java as an alternative way to make a singleton. For this singleton, I need the Context. How would I create an enum Singleton with a parameter(e.g. Context).

```
public enum MyFactory{
INSTANCE;
public Context context;

//How do I make sure that this enum gets it's context set?

}
```

Note: I guess this isn't necessarily an Android question, but because of the context object in question... maybe theres a better way to do this?

Comment: quick answer: you can't because the enum class is loaded before the context is initialized.

Comment: what is usually done is that everywhere you need a context, you have it as a parameter to you method.

Comment: getInstance(Context context) ... and remeber too pass Application context

Comment: He can't use getInstance(Context context) he specifically said he does not have the context available when he needs to access it!

Comment: *he does not have the context available when he needs to access it!* seriously, it is hard to belive ... if you have to use somthing that needs context youa are "in the context itself"  (activity,service) or have context (BroadcastReciver)

Comment: njzk2 and Selvin I'm fine with have a method (getInstance(Context)) but how do I stop the enum INSTANCE from being used directly? can my INSTANCE be set to private? Maybe this is stemming from my inexperience with enums.

Comment: could you tell more why you need a context in enum? why don't you use static helper class with static method `static ObjectThatNeedsContext Helper.getObject(enum, context)` which simple take it from some `static hashmap<enum, ObjectThatNeedsContext>` (or create if there is no object for key)

Comment: enums are bad for performance

Comment: @Selvin I'm creating a singleton but I need access to my SharedPreferences, which requires a context.

Comment: Using an enum as an alternative for ... we are at the design level here, so you should not use "something as an alternative for something else". If you need a Singleton : code a real one. If you need an Enum, so use one. You should use the right tool to do your job... you will not try to plant a nail with a screwdriver even if it should works, isn't it ?

Comment: Using an enum is the best way to create a Singleton in Java. From Joshua Bloch himself.

Answer (score 0):

You could derive your own class from the Application class. In the `onCreate` method, call a static method on your enum that sets the context using the application context (`this`).

However, you should probably consider just storing your static/global data in the application class itself, since it is already a singleton. That would be a more Android way to do it.

Comment: it like a killing the mosquito with howitzer